# How to Read the last word of file and append "," if not there. UNIX

Tags: shell, unix

I want to read last word of all txt files and if "," is not present then append it with ","

I know how to append

```
for file in *.txt; do
echo ',' >> "$file"
done
```

But before this code need to put if conndition and execute this only ',' is not  after the last of  the file.

eg. A text file abcd.txt has following data

`hello how are you hope you are good`

Now i have to chech wheather ","(comma) is present at the end of file or not
here " good" is the last line and if "," is not then append ","

i.e `hello how are you hope you are good,`

Same this check for all files and append "," if not present.

Please help

Comment: What do you mean by `last word of all txt files`? Is it last word in file's content or filename? Some examples will be better.

Comment: Please see the exmaple i have updated

Comment: If file content is `hello how are you hope you are very,good` Do you want it to become `hello how are you hope you are very,good,` or just leave it as is?

Comment: The question talks about _"words"_. Do you in fact only care about the absolutely last character of the file? What should happen if the file ends in newlines? Or in `good.)`, or `good,).`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Alex H. pointed out, you could use `tail` to check the last character.

Based on the test, you can modify the file with `sed`:

```
for file in *.txt; do
    if [ "$(tail -c 2 "$file")" != "," ]; then
        sed '$s/$/,/' "$file" > "$file.tmp" && mv "$file.tmp" "$file"
    fi
done
```

- `[ "$(tail -c 2 "$file")" != "," ]` - Tests that final character is not already `,`.  As @Yushi points out in his comment, the last character of the file will be `$` (end of line character) so we need `tail -c 2` to check for the character preceding it.
- `sed '$s/$/,/' "$file"` - Adds a `,` character to the end of the last line.
- `> "$file.tmp" && mv "$file.tmp" "$file"` - Just makes sure the file is modified and saved to its original name.

If on GNU/Linux, you can use the much shorter `sed -i '$s/$/,/' "$file"` to accomplish the same thing.  `-i` is the GNU `sed` option to modify the file "inplace" by creating a temporary file to replace the original (in the background).

Comment: It should be [ "$(tail -c 2 "$file")" != "," ]

as last charractor is $
so for ","
it will be ",$"

It worked when i used 2 in place of 1

Comment: @Yushi Yes, you are correct.  It should be `tail -c 2` as final character is `$`.  Post updated.

Answer (score 1):

Use *tail* to get the last characters of a file :

```
tail -c 1 filename
```

then catch its output and compare it with ","

Comment: John B.'s answer is much more detailed than mine, he should get the + :)